# Find class name of the function in python

Tags: python, class, python-class

I have multiple classes in my code. From input I can extract the function name. But to execute that function I need to know which class is that function belongs to. Is there any way to find the class name of that function (from the list of classes) ?

I tried `isinstance`, but it wont give the class name. And I also tried `__class__.name`, but it gives class name after we declare it before.  Is there any other way for this?

Comment: Are u using Jupyter? if yes, you can try writing the name of the class followed by "??" you will have a pop up window showing that!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you need, but you can call `.__dict__` on a class and then check if the name of your function is present as a key in the returned dictionary.

```
class B:
    def foo(self):pass

 B.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'foo': <function B.foo at 0x7f4861baee80>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'B' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'B' objects>, '__doc__': None})
```

But from the description it seems you have multiple `@classmethod`, which is most often used to declare customized initializers (sometimes wrongly called "constructors"), otherwise maybe get rid of the class and just declare "normal" functions.